# Check browser .m3u8 support php

Tags: php, android, safari, m3u8

How can I check browser support to play `m3u8` format with PHP.
IOS devices and the latest Mac Safari browser support it. I am able to check with the user agent but if there is a way to check `m3u8` support directly, this will be better. Because some `m3u8` files don't work in the latest Mac Safari browser, also I am not sure some Android devices are supported as well.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Using only PHP you have no other information beside from that what the 'User-Agent' header contains. This can be analyzed using the function `get_browser()`. But there is actually no information about supported media formats.

So, I would suggest to use javascript to detect it. You can follow [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12410132/html5-video-how-to-test-for-hls-playing-capability-video-canplaytype)